# Disable login on multisite web sites

Tags: admin

I have a network of sites, and of course, all of them have their own admin panel at /wp-admin.

I was wondering if it is possible to disable /wp-admin on all sites but on main site. So everybody logs in at same url `example.com/wp-admin` instead of logging in at `sub.example.com/wp-admin`.

I would later change `wp-admin` to something else using All In One WP Security plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single login point which you can redirect to from all sites in the network, and then redirect back to the subsite after a successful login. We did something similar for the WordCamp.org network:

http://meta.svn.wordpress.org/sites/trunk/wordcamp.org/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/wcorg-global-login.php

This will probably only work for subdomains, since you can't really set a cookie for a different domain. If you need to, you'll need something ajaxy to send authentication tokens between two domains.

However, I think it's going to be very tricky to actually access wp-admin of a subsite while *not* being on that subsite, unless you do some crazy rewriting voodoo shmooodo, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` substitution, etc.

If I were you I wouldn't even bother, especially if you're doing this for the sake of renaming wp-admin. There are many effective ways to protect your admin panel from bad guys, and renaming wp-admin is not one of them.

Comment: what would then be a best practice to protect admin login? As I said I used All In One WP Security. Login attempts are limited to 3, and I'm blocking IP addresses. What else can I do?

Comment: @VukBG: HTTPS, strong password, Jetpack Protect, maybe 2fa.